# Fixing Incorrect Concrete Leveler Application

Tags: concrete, garage, self-leveling-concrete

I have a 400 Square Foot garage that has a lot of gouges in the concrete floor. I purchased some primer and [Concrete Leveler](http://www.homedepot.com/p/Rapid-Set-50-lb-CTS-Concrete-Leveler-186010050/204414391) in order to fix the gouges. I made a mistake and accidentally mixed 4 times the amount of water in the concrete and applied it anyway. It looks bad, but I was hoping that there would be a way to salvage the application with another bag of the concrete leveler (Properly mixed this time). Is this the correct way to go about doing this?

I tried applying the primer on top of the incorrectly applied concrete leveler, but it seems to be absorbing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You really should remove the stuff that was mixed overly wet - that tends to make cement products very weak. As a result, it should be easy to remove - might even come out with a stiff broom, if not, stiff wire brush might well do it.

Check the labelling on your paint - in most cases you should wait **at least** 30 days before painting (or attempting to paint) any fresh concrete product.